# My Xamarin.Forms app crashes when I rapidly tap on menu items

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using master detail page for drawer layout and when I rapidly tap on master page item to navigate to detail page my application is crash.

Error is:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer from
>   native handle 0xffd4ff7c (key_handle 0x9721379).

Code behind for MasterDetail Page :

```
var ApplicationApprovalTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            ApplicationApprovalTap.Tapped += ApplicationApprovalTap_Tapped;
            masterPage.lblApplicationApproval_LABEL.GestureRecognizers.Add
            (ApplicationApprovalTap);
```

implementation :

```
        private void ApplicationApprovalTap_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsPresented = false;
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ApplicationApproval)));
            #region Change Color of Heder
            masterPage.lblApplicationStatus_LABEL.TextColor = Color.Black;
            #endregion
            #region Change color in current module
            masterPage.lblApplicationApproval_LABEL.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#f15a23");
            #endregion
            #region Change Color in other module
            masterPage.lblStatus_LABEL.TextColor = Color.Black;
            masterPage.lblApplication_LABEL.TextColor = Color.Black;
            #endregion
        }
```

Navigating to Detail Page :

`Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ApplicationApproval)));`

**I have referred following links :**

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10867/notsupportedexception-unable-to-activate-instance-of-type-activity

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40258

but did not get a proper solutions.

Comment: Curious why you're using `Activator` instead of just the constructor of the `ApplicationApproval` page

Comment: Detail = new NavigationPage(new ApplicationApproval()); I have also checked through this code but still facing issue of crash and showing me same exception.

Comment: The forum thread is quite old (Dec 2013) and may not be relevant for the issue you are having. I'm unable to reproduce the crash described [bug 40258](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40258) using its sample, [Xamarin Visual Studio latest stable](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-2-refresh/), and [Forms latest prerelease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.4.184-pre1). Please add [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [version info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/).